# Apache corrupting files by inserting response headers into file content?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, network-share

I have a windows share that users wish to access internally in-browser without authenticating. I have mounted the windows share into /mnt/Share on my Ubuntu VM. I then set the DocumentRoot directive to the mountpoint.

Apache correctly generated an index page for the directory but when clicking to download a PDF inside that share, the file was corrupted. Opening the file downloaded from Apache showed the start of the file had extra headers incorrectly saved into it on disk:

```
 09:41:18 GMT
ETag: "c4d0-5a1968dbe5c3e"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 50384
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/pdf

%PDF-1.6
%âãÏÓ
1 0 obj
<</AcroForm 5 0 R/Metadata 2 0 R/Outlines 6 0 R/Pages 3 0 R/Type/Catalog>>
endobj
5 0 obj
```

whereas when viewing the exact same file in /mnt the file starts

```
%PDF-1.6
%âãÏÓ
1 0 obj
<</AcroForm 5 0 R/Metadata 2 0 R/Outlines 6 0 R/Pages 3 0 R/Type/Catalog>>
endobj
5 0 obj
```

My /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost [IP-redacted]:80>
        ServerAdmin [redacted]
        DocumentRoot /mnt/Share

        ServerName [IP-redacted]
        ServerAlias [redacted]

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        ProxyPreserveHost On

        # Geoserver
        ProxyPass /geoserver http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver
        ProxyPassReverse /geoserver http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver

        Alias "/Share" "/mnt/Share/"
        <Directory /mnt/Share >
                Options +Indexes -FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
                EnableSendfile Off
                IndexOptions +FancyIndexing
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When researching this problem I found a possibly [related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15440388/489685) that suggested adding "EnableSendfile Off" but this has not solved my issue.

This VM happens to be in Azure and is being accessed over a private VPN to the company LAN but everything else works fine so I am not currently suspecting any networking issues.

Update: When testing more files I found some small XML files that downloaded without the corruption. All the PDF's and TIF's I've tried so far have been corrupted as above, but so far I can't tell if its the file type or the size that is the trigger.

Update 2: Here's the first packet of the HTTP response in Wireshark:
[image: Mangled packet screenshot]

Comment: What does the full response look like? From what ends up in the file (beginning in the middle of a date, it appears?), it seems like you did not get all the headers but maybe rather everything after some header value that had unexpected linebreaks somehow?

Comment: I didn't notice that, well spotted! Have traced in wireshark and there aren't any other headers before that? Also Wireshark displays the response as a hundred exactly 1350 byte packets, seems weird?

Comment: Probably not related but match trailing slashes in the Alias directice please.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up trying to get Apache to work and swapped it out for Nginx instead. This worked great and was as simple as

```
sudo systemctl stop apache2 && sudo apt install nginx
```

The equivalent config for /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default is as follows:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
        location /Share {
                alias /mnt/Share;
                autoindex on;
        }
        location /geoserver {
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver;
        }
}
```